# React js: <CopyToClipBoard> not copying values, even though state is correct for the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clipboard

I am implementing  from a react plugin called "react-copy-to-clipboard".

My component looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { FiCopy, FiDownload } from "react-icons/fi";
import { CopyToClipboard } from "react-copy-to-clipboard";

class PlayerCaption extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.downloadVid = this.downloadVid.bind(this);
    this.onCopy = this.onCopy.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      copied: false,
      value: "default text"
    };
  }
  downloadVid() {
    this.props.dwn_url();
  }

  onCopy = () => {
    this.setState({ copied: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="caption">
        <p className="video-buttons">
          <CopyToClipboard text={this.state.value} onCopy={this.onCopy}>
            <button type="button" id={this.props.id}>
              <FiCopy size={30} />
            </button>
          </CopyToClipboard>
          {this.state.copied ? <span>Copied!</span> : null}
          <button type="button" onClick={this.downloadVid} id={this.props.id}>
            <FiDownload size={30} />
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PlayerCaption;
```

My props have the correct value and the 'this.state.copied' flag changes its state - but I am unable to see any text getting copied to clipboard. 
I followed this codepen to implement the (plugin):
[https://codepen.io/nkbt/pen/eNPoQv?editors=0010]

What is incorrect about my implementation? How can I do this in vanilla JS?

Comment: When `Copied!` getting printed on screen, have you tried to paste your copied text somewhere? I think it is working fine, the plugin is working fine, when you click the copy button text is getting copied, you need to varify it by pasting somewhere else.

Comment: I did - doesn't print latest thing copied - I am on create react app - is it an env issue?

Comment: Your value is `default text`,it will always print that only. You are never changing that.

Comment: How and where can I change that?

Comment: What is your requirement? When should this value get change?

Comment: on click of the button, the text that is contained in this.props.copy should be copied

Comment: Instead of `text={this.state.value}` you can directly do this `text={this.props.copy}` and don't need to maintain state.

Comment: yaasss this is what I wanted! Thanks a ton! I wonder how I would manage if I needed to do some other activity and change state though

Answer (score 0):

Are you in production or development environment? For production, clipboard is only supported for pages served over HTTPS. Make sure you have work over there.

Comment: inside dev env.